# Mysql Ordering Query

Tags: sql, mysql

Hello I want to run a query to get the last five records from a table, but in reverse order. Currently I have:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
```

which isn't quite what I want.

For example if the last five records are

15
16
17
18
19

I want them returned as

15
16
17
18
19

Not 19 18 17 16 15 which is what the above does.

How do I achieve this? If I change DESC to ASC it gives 1 2 3 4 5 so that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a sub query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) AS tmp
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: MySQL (at least) requires an alias. If you run this query, you will probably see this error:

    ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: So how do I do it?

None of these work, I get mysql errors when I try and output the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub-select to do that:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) AS t ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Are you using a realllllly old version of MySQL perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) T1 ORDER BY id ASC;